# ASP.NET Core MVC Radio button on change event call controller action

Tags: ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple two radio buttons in my ASP.NET Core MVC app, by default A1 radio button is selected and it calls A1 (controller and action).

I made a change in code to call A2 controller `Index` action (`HttpPost`), but it isn't working

`Index.cshtml`:

```
 <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" onclick="'getA1Rates()'" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA1" checked />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA1"> A1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" onclick="'getA2Rates()'" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA2" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA2"> A2 </label>
    </div>
```

`.cshtml` javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getA1Rates() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            URL: "/CodesController/Index/",
            data: { id: $('#flexRadioA1').val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success")
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
    function getA2Rates() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            URL: "/CodesController/Index/",
            data: { id: $('#flexRadioA2').val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success")
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My `CodesController`:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
     // blah..blah..
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string data)
 {
     // blah..blah..
 }
```

My browser console also looks good I don't see any $ undefined error or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you  use  this way : [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) ?

Add some change to your code:

```
 <input class="form-check-input"  type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA1" checked value="A1"/>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA2" value="A2" />
```

And :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#flexRadioA1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({...
        $('#flexRadioA2').click(function () {
            $.ajax({...
       })
    })
```

Change your parameter in your index action like:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
        {
           ...
        }
```

**OR**

use `onclick="getA1Rates()"` not `onclick="'getA1Rates()'"`  , and  add value and change parameter like before, and use your javascript code.

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA1" onclick="getA1Rates()" checked value="A1" />
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA2" value="A2" onclick="getA2Rates()" />
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @Sayeed Ahmed Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: I still have one more issue After selecting the A2 from radio button I see controller Action successfully passes A2 related data to my view, but I still see A1 data in my page when it lands finally. A1 is selected by default. Any suggestions what's wrong in my code

Comment: @SayeedAhmed What do you mean "still see A1 data in my page when it lands finally." ? Could you create a new post to describe it clearly ? So that we can help you.

Comment: I have created a new post; can you have a look @qing-guo..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743781/on-calling-http-post-from-ajax-index-view-doesnt-update-with-httppost-action-da

Comment: @SayeedAhmed Ok, please see my answer in that link.