# On Calling HTTP post from Ajax Index view doesn't update with HTTPPost Action Data in MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In my requirement By default I display ID 1 value which is A1 from my radio button, when user selects anotehr Radio button A2 the I make an HTTPPost Ajax call Index Action to display A2 related values however I still see default A1 values which is calling HTTPGet Action data in my View.

My Radio button controls

```
 <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA1" checked />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA1"> A1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA2" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA2"> A2</label>
    </div>
```

Ajax Call

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
 $('#flexRadioA1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/RtCd/Index'
            })
        });           
            $('#flexRadioA2').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/RtCd/Index',
                    data: { Id: 2 }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My Controller HTTPPost method Action

```
[HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                var uatContext = _context.RtCd.Include(r => r.Audit);
                var list = (from r in uatContext
                            join u in _context.Util
                            on r.UtilId equals u.UtilId
                            where r.RtCd != "" && r.UtilId == 1
                            select new RtCdViewModel
                            {
                                RtCdId = r.RtCdId,
                                RtCd = r.RtCd,
                                UtilName = u.UtilName
                            });
                return View(await list.ToListAsync());
            }
      [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int Id)
            {
                var uatContext = _context.RtCd.Include(r => r.Audit);
                var list = (from r in uatContext
                            join u in _context.Util
                            on r.UtilId equals u.UtilId
                            where r.RtCd != "" && r.UtilId == Id
                            select new RtCdViewModel
                            {
                                RtCdId = r.RtCdId,
                                RtCd = r.RtCd,
                                UtilName = u.UtilName
                            });
                return View(await list.ToListAsync());
            }
```

My .csHtml file

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCCode.ViewModel.RtCdViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RT List";
}
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RtcD)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UtilName)
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        }
```

I see data is successfully binding to my view controls with Id value 2 which I passed in Ajax call but once it gets finally lnding my View I still see old data whose Id is default 1 value instead of Id 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

In Index POST method, return `list` is a `IEnumerable<RtCdViewModel>` type.

```
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int Id)
            { 
              ...
              return Json(list);
             }
```

Index view:

1.add  `<span id="b">`  and `<span id="c">` to wrap `DisplayFor` in a span.

2. add success method to change  the display value.

the full index code is like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCCode.ViewModel.RtCdViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RT List";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="b">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RtCd)
            </span>
        </td>
        <td >
            <span id="c">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UtilName)
            </span>           
        </td>
    </tr>
}
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA1" checked />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA1"> A1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioA2" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefaultA2"> A2</label>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#flexRadioA1').click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: '/RtCd/IndexA1',
               success: function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {                      
                    $('#b').html(result[i].rtCd);
                    $('#c').html(result[i].utilName);
                }
            }
           })
       });
               $('#flexRadioA2').click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: '/RtCd/Index',
                       data: { Id: 2 },                      
                       success: function (result) {
                       for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                       {                        
                        $('#b').html(result[i].rtCd);
                        $('#c').html(result[i].utilName);
                       }                   
                        }
                   })
               });
           });
</script>
```

result:

[image]

**Update**:

RtCdController :

```
   public class RtCdController : Controller
  {
        public List<RtCdAudit> rtCdAudits;
        public List<Util> Util ;
        public RtCdController() 
        {
            rtCdAudits = new List<RtCdAudit>();
            rtCdAudits.Add(new RtCdAudit() { RtCdId = 1, RtCd = "Anoop", UtilId =1});
            rtCdAudits.Add(new RtCdAudit() { RtCdId = 2, RtCd = "Other", UtilId = 2});

            Util = new List<Util>();
            Util.Add(new Util() { RtCdId = 1, RtCd = "Anoop", UtilName = "123", UtilId = 1 });
            Util.Add(new Util() { RtCdId = 2, RtCd = "Other", UtilName = "A2", UtilId = 2});
        }       
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //var uatContext = _context.RtCd.Include(r => r.Audit);
            var list = (from r in rtCdAudits
                        join u in Util
                        on r.UtilId equals u.UtilId
                        where r.RtCd != "" && r.UtilId == 1
                        select new RtCdViewModel
                        {
                            RtCdId = r.RtCdId,
                            RtCd = r.RtCd,
                            UtilName = u.UtilName
                        });
            return View( list);
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexA1()
    {
        //var uatContext = _context.RtCd.Include(r => r.Audit);
        var list = (from r in rtCdAudits
                    join u in Util
                    on r.UtilId equals u.UtilId
                    where r.RtCd != "" && r.UtilId == 1
                    select new RtCdViewModel
                    {
                        RtCdId = r.RtCdId,
                        RtCd = r.RtCd,
                        UtilName = u.UtilName
                    });
        return Json(list);
    }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int Id)
        {
            //var uatContext = _context.RtCd.Include(r => r.Audit);
            var list = (from r in rtCdAudits
                        join u in Util
                        on r.UtilId equals u.UtilId
                        where r.RtCd != "" && r.UtilId == Id
                        select new RtCdViewModel
                        {
                            RtCdId = r.RtCdId,
                            RtCd = r.RtCd,
                            UtilName = u.UtilName
                        });
            return Json(list);
        }
    }
```

Util:

```
 public class Util
    {
        public int UtilId { get; set; }
        public int RtCdId { get; set; }
        public string RtCd { get; set; }
        public string UtilName { get; set; }
    }
```

RtCdAudit:

```
public class RtCdAudit
    {
        public string RtCd { get; set; }
        public int RtCdId { get; set; }
        public int UtilId { get; set; }        
    }
```

RtCdViewModel:

```
  public class RtCdViewModel
    {
        public int RtCdId { get; set; }
        public string RtCd { get; set; }
        public string UtilName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you share me your sample code the above one. I'll try to replicate the same and update my code accordingly. as of now It's now working

Comment: @SayeedAhmed I have add my sample code, and Index view is the same. Please have a look.

Comment: I can now see the values in Ui from A1 to A2 however it remains same in A2. If I click back to A1 it doesn't shows A1 values.. It was persisted on A2 only.

Comment: @SayeedAhmed If we need to change A1 and A2 value, we  should so some change at A1 ajax too, please have a check my update, add a new action `IndexA1` and success method for A1ajax.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contributions for my queries. I'm just curious to know about the properties which we are referring to rtCd and utilName in a JavaScript call but in Model we haven't declared as a lowercase instead we have declared as (RtCd,UtilName). Thoughts..

Comment: @SayeedAhmed You are welcome:) "the properties which we are referring to rtCd and utilName in a JavaScript call ' You can use `F12` to see the source tab , and set a breakpoint at the result in the `<script>` in the broswer , you can see the JavaScript declared as a lowercase.  like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUu5T.png